# How to setup domain category to AWS EC2

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 server AWS EC2 (EC2-A, EC2-B).

Now, I have 1 domain http://my-domain.com call to website in EC2-A (/var/www/html/website1).

I want setup domain category http://my-domain.com/category call to website in EC2-B (/var/www/html/website2).

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a master on this subject, but I would most likely use one of the following approaches:

1. If possible, use `category.my-domain.com` and then make the DNS server point to the correct EC2 instance; or
2. Use a NAT instance that redirects the traffic to the correct instance based on the url pattern. That is, all requests would be made to the NAT instance, which in turn would forward it to the correct instance. To achieve that I would probably choose [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) and do something like explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/566862/haproxy-url-pattern-forwarding).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want using subdomain.

Comment: In 2. you wouldn't rely in subdomains. Take a look at the last link I pasted.